# Linux - Multiple service statuses with one command

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to retrieve a list of multiple service statuses in Unix. I'm using the `service` command: [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man8/service.8.html).

The statuses all start with the `transmission-daemon` string, for example.

I require the ability to list multiple services' statuses, **with a single command**. Here is what I'm currently trying (and failing) with:

Here I'm trying to grab a list of statuses using `grep`.

```
service $(ls /etc/init.d | grep "transmission-daemon") status
```

Here I'm trying to list all statuses, and then `grep` for them.

```
service --status-all | grep "transmission-daemon"
```

*This produces the following, which isn't much help:*

[image: Multiple transmission daemons via grep and service --status-all]

How can I effectively achieve what I require with a single command, so that I can then continue piping to `awk` for further customisation?

**Desired example output:**

```
transmission-daemon started
transmission-daemon2 stopped
transmission-daemon3 started
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have much to say except that:

- Your `ls | grep` thing seems really awkward and wrong to me
- To solve your `grep` issue, is it that `service` outputs to *stderr*? How about with a redirection of *stderr* to *stdout*?

  ```
  service --status-all 2>&1 | grep "transmission-daemon"
  ```

(but doing this also seems really awkward and wrong to me).

---

Apparently you want to run your services with the *status* command, right? How about using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for s in /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon* ; do
    service "$(basename "$s")" status
done
```

In one line:

```
bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob; for s in /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon* ; do service "$(basename "$s")" status; done'
```

This gives:

[image]

Hope this will put you on the right track (or at least on a better one)!

Comment: Yes, this example you give works! However you're completely correct - it's really awkward and also takes a while. Any alternatives? +1 for the meantime :)

Comment: And also, I then have to further figure out the `+` for started, `?` etc. There's got to be another way...

Comment: @Jimbo please see my edit.

Comment: This is nice - is there a way to have this in *one command* as my question says? That's the goal - off-topic it'll be interpreted by `PHP` and `exec()` :)

Comment: @Jimbo I don't understand your _one command_ requirement. If you consider this a bash script it will be one command. If you want to drive it from php, just `exec()` directly the `service` command with the appropriate arguments (here `transmission-daemonX status`). Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Okay, there will be a variable number of `transmission-daemonX` statuses. There could be 3, 5 or 0. Users of this application will not always have access to create a bash script on their server and execute it, it's gotta be contained within an exec in PHP. So, in order to perform an exec, it's gotta be a single liner - to get a list of all daemons, and also their statuses. There'll be additional overhead if I perform two requests over SSH (to the server) to first get a list, and then individually figure out each status. It should be possible in one command. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jimbo `bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob; for s in /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon* ; do service "$(basename "$s")" status; done'` is one command (`bash`) with two argument (`-c`) and the big string. Does this count?

Comment: Nice, almost there! I get an `unrecognised service` for each one - I'm guessing this is because it's doing a service check for `/etc/init.d/X` when it should be checking for just `X`. Maybe a replace to finish this off? :)

Comment: @Jimbo just look at my edited version... I added `basename` to make things work.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the effort - this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `find`'s `-exec` option:

```
-exec command ;
     Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All following arguments to
     find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting 
     of `;' is encountered.  The string '{}' is replaced by the current file 
     name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, 
     not just in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find. Both
     of these constructions might need to be escaped (with a '\') or quoted to 
     protect them from expansion by the shell.
```

Specifically (split for legibility):

```
find /etc/init.d/ -name "transmission-daemon*" \
  -exec bash -c 'service $(basename "{}") status' \;
```

And on one line:

```
find /etc/init.d/ -name "transmission-daemon*" -exec bash -c 'service $(basename "{}") status' \;
```

Comment: Better written as `find /etc/init.d/ -name "transmission-daemon*" -exec bash -c 'service "$(basename "$0")" status' {} \;`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf why? as long as the `{}` is quoted, you should have no problem with weird characters and services won't have spaces in their names.

Comment: No you're wrong. If e.g., a filename contains a quote you'll have a surprise. The `{}` should never be used the way you used it. Moreover, if the filename contains spaces, you'll have problems too, so you should also quote `$(basename "$0")`. Try it! But then I agree that services are very unlikely to have weird characters. But then it's just a matter of good practices that you apply without even thinking about them when you're used to them `;)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I have tried it, it works for the services I have installed. I agree with your point in principal but these are `init.d` services, their names are pretty standard, they should never contain quotes for example because they would not work with `service`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way the easiest to remember:

```
for s in /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon*; do service $(basename $s) status; done
```